# Tabbed file explorer for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, software-rec, tabs

Is there a utility which integrates with Windows 8's File Explorer and gives tabs? I don't want dual pane. Just tabs. And I want it to integrate with Windows 8's own File Explorer preferably as I don't want to lose the Ribbon.

Comment: By tabs what do you mean?

Comment: Like tabbed finder in OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Search on [this link](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm). Other than this, you should have some care while asking for product recommendations.

Comment: try QTTabBar: http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that [Clover](http://ejie.me/) and [QTTabBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qttabbar/) are some options.

Comment: Clover is great. It’s a little unstable, flicker, and doesn’t have too many features, but it’s pretty wonderful. Being based on Chromium, it shares all the features that made me like Chrome at the beginning. Sadly, I have given up on Chrome, so I don’t know if I can hold out hope for Clover’s future.

Comment: I am assuming you gave up on Chrome because it became too bloated. I don't think that will be Clover's fate. As an aside, which browser do you use now?

Comment: Actually, I gave up because the Google devs became horrible, tyrannical fascists who ignore user feedback and do whatever they want, including ruining the browser. The problem is that they are doing those things to the Chromium code, so anything based on it will inherit the negative changes (or else require a lot of work to undo). I’m still using (an old version of) Chrome for now, but will likely eventually switch to Firefox (I intend to keep all of my data, so it’s a lot of work to migrate it all).

Comment: I switched from Firefox to Chrome because Firefox became a resource hog. And now I notice, chrome is the same. And Chrome removed the smooth scrolling flag on Windows. How mean!

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I tried Firefox years ago but was disappointed with how bogged down it got when you add a few extensions. Unfortunately the Chrome devs are trying to strip Chrome down to nothing and offset all functionality to extensions (while at the same time, limiting what extensions can do), so now you have to have dozens and dozens of active extensions for it to do anything. Plus, since they changed it so that absolutely everything gets its own process, there is a *lot* of extra CPU and memory overhead, making Chrome a fat, bloated, gas-bag. Google is finished.

Comment: And there is no credible cross-platform alternative. I wouldn't mind switching to IE but it doesn't have the extensions I need and it isn't cross-platform. Chrome is like a necessary evil now. We all want to give it up but can't.

Comment: I think Google treated it like drugs; they gave us a free taste of something pleasurable, then once we were hooked, they ruined it and made it as bad as they like knowing that we are stuck. I for one am continuing to use an older version of Chrome/Chromium for the time being until I can migrate away altogether. As a close alternative, I am considering some of the Chromium-based projects like Comodo, Iron, and Torch. They use Chromium as the base and add on (or put back) the things that users actually want but Google obstinately refuses.

Comment: "treated it like drugs". Perfect description!